# Java FocusListener for JTable and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, focuslistener

I'm making a basic Total Commander copy in Java. There's two JTable next to each other. I made a FocusListener to know which JTable was used last. It worked perfectly if the user clicked on a row, but not if clicked under the rows. My JTables are in JScrollPanes. I tried to add the FocusListener to the scrollpanes too, but that didn't work either.

Is there a way to get info if the user clicked inside the frame of a JTable?

```
JTable leftSideTable = new JTable(leftSideData);
JTable rightSideTable = new JTable(rightSideData);
JScrollPane leftScroll = new JScrollPane();
JScrollPane rightScroll = new JScrollPane();

leftScroll.setViewportView(leftSideTable);
rightScroll.setViewportView(rightSideTable);
```

And the listener's function:

```
public void focusGained(FocusEvent e){
    if(e.getSource().equals(leftSideTable))
        leftSide.set(true); //if leftSide is true leftTable is focused
    else if(e.getSource().equals(rightSideTable))
        leftSide.set(false);
}
```

I can't really add more relevant code. The ScrollPanes are added into main panel with GroupLayout.

[image: Total Commander Bug]

Comment: Errr and the code? You need to add a [MCVE] for us to be able to help you...

Comment: I added some code.

Comment: That is not enough code. It's minimal, sure, but neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: Why would you need more code? That's not a bug. I'm asking a general question. Is there a way to know if the user clicked inside the frame of a JTable, not the rows of it? The focusGained event only knows if one of the rows were clicked, not the whole JTable.

Comment: `Is there a way to get info if the user clicked inside the frame of a JTable?` How about a [MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)?

Comment: That worked, thank you!